# Calculating Free Memory using kstat vs vmstat vs mdb

Tags: solaris, virtual-memory, vmstat

In attempting to calculate the free memory under Solaris 10, I noticed I get different results using `vmstat` versus `kstat` or `mdb`.

The basic commands:

```
/usr/bin/kstat -p unix::system_pages:freemem | cut -f 2
/usr/bin/vmstat 1 1 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $5 / 1024 }'
echo ::memstat | mdb -k | awk '/cachelist/ { print $4 }'
echo ::memstat | mdb -k | awk '/freelist/ { print $4 }'
```

The `kstat` and (the two) `memstat` commands give essentially identical results 147266MB, whereas the `vmstat` command returns 167030MB.

Can someone explain the difference please?